# How to customize error log format in ProxySQL?

Tags: proxysql

I've notice some *syntax error* in my proxysql error log (`/var/lib/proxysql/proxysql.log`):

```
Error during query on (0,1.2.3.4,3306): 1064, syntax error, unexpected '-'
```

But they're report only the error and not the query that cause it.

Is it possible to include in the proxysql.log also the query?

Eventually log only the queries that go in error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute `Set mysql-verbose_query_error = true` when you begin the database connection in your applications.

FYI:

[How to change variables](https://proxysql.com/documentation/global-variables/)

[Functionality regarding the variable: mysql-verbose_query_error](https://proxysql.com/Documentation/global-variables/mysql-variables/)

Comment: @IvanButtinoni You may check out the updated links.